# Scala 3 Tasty Reflection Macro: CyclicReference

Tags: scala, scala-macros, dotty, scala-3

I'm trying to access the parameters of a method that is being implemented as a macro.

```
object Macros {
    def impl()(using Quotes): Expr[Unit] = {    
        import quotes.reflect._
        val params: List[List[ValDef]] = {
            def nearestEnclosingMethodParams(owner: Symbol): List[List[ValDef]] =
                owner match {
                    case defSym if defSym.isDefDef =>
                        defSym.tree.asInstanceOf[DefDef].paramss
                    case _ =>
                        nearestEnclosingMethod(owner.owner)
                }
            nearestEnclosingMethodParams(Symbol.spliceOwner)
        }
        println(params) // I would do something useful with params names and types here
        '{()}
    }
}
```

The call-site could look something like:

```
object Test {
    def foo(a: String, b: Int) = Foo.impl
    @main def run(): Unit = {
        val x = foo("blah", 24)
        ()
    }
}

object Foo {
    inline def impl = ${ Macros.impl() }
}
```

For now, I'm getting a `CyclicReference` error when the macro expands, upon `defSym.tree`. I understand that `defSym.tree` is cyclic because it includes the code of the currently expanding macro, but I still need to access a "tree" version of the method definition to access its name and parameters, without the method's body. How can I get that information without cycling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in the recently released version of Scala 3.0.0-RC1.

using `defSym.tree` in the `def foo(a: String, b: Int) = Foo.impl` example now works just fine and just uses an `EmptyTree` for the macro body. You can easily extract any information you need from the method argument, or type hierarchy where `foo` is defined, which was my use-case.

```
DefDef(
    foo,
    List(
        List(
            ValDef(
                a,
                TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),object Predef),type String)],
                EmptyTree
            ), 
            ValDef(
                b,
                TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),class Int)],
                EmptyTree
            )
        )
    ),
    TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Unit)],
    EmptyTree
)
```